# Как сделать такой скролл?

Tags: javascript, html

Хотел бы повторить плавный скролл с сайта https://www.cieffemilano.it/en/about/. Как ето сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там используется библиотека [locomotive-scroll](https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll) Превью: https://locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll/
Тот же скролл бар, похожие эффекты. Там достаточно большой набор разных настроек, насколько я понял на сайте из вашего вопроса используется метод

```
has-scroll-smooth
has-scroll-init
```

На весь html. (классы к тегу html, которым обернут весь сайт)
В любом случае, поигравшись с этой либой вы сможете достичь тех же результатов)